# Is there a way of creating Biglake Tables through Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#ExternalDataConfiguration.FIELDS.source_format) I see no reference to [BigLake tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/biglake-intro). I wonder if there's a way of setting `ExternalDataConfiguration` to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out: if you provide a [connection ID](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#ExternalDataConfiguration.FIELDS.connection_id) it will be used for setting the table as a BigLake Table (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73987775/9944075 on how to create the connection)